# In binary classification, when evaluating in .train() mode my model gets a high accuracy on my test data

Tags: python, pytorch

I use pytorch train a binary model. When evaluating in model.train() mode my model gets a high accuracy on my test data than model.eval().I used the BN layer

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I trained a binary model，When evaluating in model.train() mode my model gets a high accuracy on my test data than model.eval().

Comment: Are you using a BN layer right at the input?